# Data table does not refresh on event change. - Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular4-httpclient

On trigger or call of change function the pagination data does not update it still holds the previous data rendered on init call.

TS code :

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/').subscribe(
            data => {
                this.DataArray = data.json();
                console.log(data.json());
            }
        );
    }


    public change(event): void { 
       let newVal = event.target.value;

        this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/').subscribe(
            data => {
                this.DataArray = []
                this.DataArray.push(data.json()[newVal]);
            }
        );
    }
```

HTML code

```
 <tr *ngFor="let data of DataArray">
     <td><a href="javascript:"><i class="fa fa fa-eye" data-
     toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a 
     href="javascript:"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a 
     href="javascript:"><i class="fa fa-line-chart"></i>
     </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="javascript:"><i class="fa fa-trash-o">
     </i></a></td>
     <td>{{data.id}}</td>           
     <td>{{data.title}}</td>                            
     <td>{{data.type}}</td>
     <td>{{data.smsFlag ? "Yes":"No"}}</td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: Are you sure the data you are getting from `data.json()[newVal]` is correct?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, yes the data is correct. I can see that gets updated on the html page. But the pagination still contains the previous data loaded in ngOnInit.